# TestFlight.dll Error

Tags: dll, xamarin.ios, testflight

I've got a problem with the TestFlight.dll and binding it into Monotouch.
I have already loaded the .dll into my references and added to additional build arguments the
flags

> -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -llibTestflight.a -force_load {ProjectDir}/libTestflight.a"

but while compiling i got this error:

> ld: file not found:
>   /var/folders/z9/sbglbns52gb75xy5c41ck1s40000gn/T/tmp1b28d639.tmp/libTestFlight.a
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided
>   to gcc:....

Thank you very mutch;)

Alex

Answer (score 2):

If your `TestFlight.dll` is recent it should have been compiled with the `[LinkWith]` attribute.

This means you do not have to provide `gcc_flags` - the tooling should be extracting them from the assembly and do this automagically (just as `libTestlight.a` is extracted from the .dll).

What happens if you compile without adding `gcc_flags` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo at the end, a missing $:

-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -llibTestflight.a -force_load **$**{ProjectDir}/libTestflight.a"

Comment: What about this: -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lTestFlight -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libTestflight.a"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem..

I dont exactly know the problem but i recreated the TestFlight.dll and used the Flags:

```
-nosymbolstrip -nostrip -cxx -gcc_flags "-lgcc_eh -L${ProjectDir} -ltestflight -ObjC"
```

@poupou: without the gcc_flags i got the same error message.. I think the error was thrown by the TestFlight.dll

nevertheless thanks to both of you;)

Comment: In addition i changed the bindings to the sample of ayoung:
https://github.com/ayoung/monotouch-testflight